# How to prevent node process exit in a callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js

For example if there is a callback function, after running the callback function, run`process.exit()`

```js
function Test(callback) {
  callback();
  return process.exit();
}
```

How can I prevent process.exit() execute or prevent process exit in the callback function.

Comment: So effectively you wan to control the code that is provided as a callback?

Comment: @Mushroomator I am using a third party tool, but it has a function, after running the callback, it calls `process.exit`, but I dont want the process exit.

Comment: @ChenLee, fork it and change the code, use a different tool, or write your own. Why use something with hard-coded effects you don't want?

Answer (score 1):

You could throw an exception at the end of the callback function and catch it outside `Test`:

```
function Test(callback) {
  callback();
  return process.exit();
}

try {
  Test(() => {
    console.log('some code');
    throw 'Exception';
  });
} catch {}

console.log('process.exit() skipped');
```

Running example with exception : https://wandbox.org/permlink/UtDdMh4cHjUPURB8

Running example without exception: https://wandbox.org/permlink/Ih5L1PG1gJKMTJYN